# What layer should be perform unit test in ASP.NET Web API that using dependency injection

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

im new with unit test and i have watch all youtube video and article that give tutorial of how to implement unit test on ASP.NET Web API , and most of them is suggest me to test on Controller layer, even in Microsoft Article, its using dependency injection in controller. Additionally , its suggest me to perform unit test on Controller method only and mocking IRepository or IService, but im curious that why they don't suggest to test on Service or Repository layer, those 2 layer is mostly responsible for implement logic, so we have to check the logic, right?

Suppose i have a method to get all product like this:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>> Get()
    {
        return Ok(_productService.GetProducts());
    }
}
```

should i implement testing on GetProducts() method inside ProductService to check its behaviour or just perform unit test on Get() method in Controller to check if its return response 200 or not?